# How can I show the same HTML 5 YOUTUBE Video twice on a website without loading it twice?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, html5-canvas, html5-video

How can I show the same HTML5 YOUTUBE Video twice on a website without loading it twice?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496605/how-can-i-show-the-same-html-5-video-twice-on-a-website-without-loading-it-twice) you are taught to display a same html 5 video twice without having to load twice. But I want to know how to do it with a youtube video, using the IFRAME tag. The link is taught using the canvas, but I can not do the same with the iframe. Can you duplicate the video even with the iframe? Or is there a way to "catch" the iframe video tag? (I've tried, but it has an "access denied" error). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809971/load-same-youtube-video-on-2-diffrent-iframes-without-loading-it-twice) might help, too.

This is just an example, but I wanted to do something like this:

[Original youtube video.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWCRp.png)

[image]

[My "site" with 1 youtube video and several canvas.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZoyK.png)

[image]

I wanted to take this video is to post several in my site, enabling multiple simultaneous playbacks. As this would take a lot of the internet, I wanted to get the current frame of the original video simultaneously and place them on several canvases, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496605/how-can-i-show-the-same-html-5-video-twice-on-a-website-without-loading-it-twice) teaches you to do just that, but using videos (< video> tag). I want to do this using youtube videos.
**I want all players to play / pause at the same time, as if they were copying each other**

Comment: Youtube streams videos, not uploads them. So you've already got what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

At least, not legitimately.  There is no provision in the YouTube Iframe API for granting you access to the underlying video element.